# Removing duplicate JSON when new data is fetched

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, function, npm

I have an array which has duplicate data:

```js
var array = [
    { "licenceNum": "12345", state:"NV", country:"US" },
    { "licenceNum": "12345", state:"OR", country:"US" },
    { "licenceNum": "10849", state:"CA", country:"US" },
    { "licenceNum": "12345", state:"OR", country:"US" },
    { "licenceNum": "12345", state:"OR", country:"CA" },
    { "licenceNum": "22424", state:"OR", country:"CA" },
    { "licenceNum": "22424", state:"OR", country:"CA" },
    { "licenceNum": "12345", state:"NM", country:"US" },
    { "licenceNum": "A7846", state:"CA", country:"US" },
    { "licenceNum": "10849", state:"CA", country:"US" },
    { "licenceNum": "10849", state:"CA", country:"US" },
    { "licenceNum": "B7037", state:"WA", country:"US" }
];
```

Some of the duplicate data is supposed to be that way, others are exact dupes.

I've tried to remove the duplicates, and only keep the originals but cant seem to figure out how.

```js
const unique = [...new Map( unique.map( item =>
  [ item.licenceNum, item ]
)).values()]
```

Except this removes all the other keys since its only matching on one field.

How can I remove the duplicates so I end up with:

```js
var uniqueArray = [
    { "licenceNum": "12345", state:"NV", country:"US" },
    { "licenceNum": "12345", state:"OR", country:"US" },
    { "licenceNum": "10849", state:"CA", country:"US" },
    { "licenceNum": "12345", state:"NM", country:"US" },
    { "licenceNum": "B7037", state:"WA", country:"US" },
    { "licenceNum": "12345", state:"OR", country:"CA" },
    { "licenceNum": "22424", state:"OR", country:"CA" }
];
```

But also when I re-fetch the original `array` from an API, can I check the `uniqueArray` to see it there's an exisiting match before pushing the data to it?

Everything I've found leads to using `jQuery` or `_unique.js` but I want to use vanilla JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a slightly modified version of the code from @Spectric.

```
var array = [
    { "licenceNum": "12345", state:"NV", country:"US" },
    { "licenceNum": "12345", state:"OR", country:"US" },
    { "licenceNum": "10849", state:"CA", country:"US" },
    { "licenceNum": "12345", state:"OR", country:"CA" },
    { "licenceNum": "12345", state:"NM", country:"US" },
    { "licenceNum": "A7846", state:"CA", country:"US" },
    { "licenceNum": "10849", state:"CA", country:"US" },
    { "licenceNum": "10849", state:"CA", country:"US" },
    { "licenceNum": "B7037", state:"WA", country:"US" }
];


var uniqueArray = [...new Set(array.map(e => e.licenceNum + e.state + e.country))].map(e => array.find(f => f.licenceNum + f.state + f.country == e));
console.log(uniqueArray);

``
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the unique `state` property values with the [`Set` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/Set) and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), then map over the resulting array and get the object with the same `state` property:

```js
var array = [
    { "licenceNum": "12345", state:"NV", country:"US" },
    { "licenceNum": "12345", state:"OR", country:"US" },
    { "licenceNum": "10849", state:"CA", country:"US" },
    { "licenceNum": "12345", state:"OR", country:"US" },
    { "licenceNum": "12345", state:"NM", country:"US" },
    { "licenceNum": "A7846", state:"CA", country:"US" },
    { "licenceNum": "10849", state:"CA", country:"US" },
    { "licenceNum": "10849", state:"CA", country:"US" },
    { "licenceNum": "B7037", state:"WA", country:"US" }
];


var uniqueArray = [...new Set(array.map(e => e.state))].map(e => array.find(f => f.state == e))
console.log(uniqueArray)
```

Comment: Sorry, what happens when I have an additional country listed with the same number or state then it seems to be discarded. Question edited to reflect - bad copy paste on my end!